# Setting a delay on a UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uialertview

I have a a check that is run in my code. If the check returns true, I execute an animation and display a UIAlertView to the user. My problem is that i don't know how to delay the UIAlertView until the animation is completed. So, currently, the UIAlertView is displayed and the animation is seen running in the background. I'd appreciate any help with this. Here is the relevant code:

```
BOOL isComplete = [self checkJigsawCompleted:droppedInPlace withTag:tag];
        if (isComplete) {

            [stopWatchTimer invalidate];
            stopWatchTimer = nil;
            [self updateTimer];

            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
            imgGrid.alpha = 0;
            imgBackground.alpha = 0;
            [UIView commitAnimations]; 
            NSString *completedMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You completed the puzzle in: %@", lblStopwatch.text];


            UIAlertView *jigsawCompleteAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]   //show alert box with option to play or exit
                                  initWithTitle: @"Congratulations!" 
                                  message:completedMessage 
                                  delegate:self 
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"I'm done" 
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Play again",nil];
            [jigsawCompleteAlert show];
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to the [blocks-based animation method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html):

```
if (isComplete) {

    [stopWatchTimer invalidate];
    stopWatchTimer = nil;
    [self updateTimer];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        imgGrid.alpha = 0;
        imgBackground.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSString *completedMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You completed the puzzle in: %@", lblStopwatch.text];
        UIAlertView *jigsawCompleteAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]   //show alert box with option to play or exit
                                            initWithTitle: @"Congratulations!" 
                                            message:completedMessage 
                                            delegate:self 
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"I'm done" 
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Play again",nil];
        [jigsawCompleteAlert show];
    }];
}
```

Comment: As easy as that! Thanks. Can you tell me the significance of the "f" in `1.0f`?

Comment: The "f" is to denote that it's a float.

Comment: By "it's" you mean the number of seconds? Is this necessary or just good practice? I've seen several examples without the `f`.

Comment: Not necessary, but common practice. Yes, the time duration is in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add an handler for when your animation is completed:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
...
```

Of course, you should provide an implementation for `animationDidStop:finished:context:` where you display the dialog.

Keep in mind that `beginAnimations` and its family of methods are discouraged as of iOS 4.0 and block based animations are the preferred way to go. But if you want to support iOS 3.x, the above is the solution to your problem.